# Side Menu in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I am using Eclipse + GWT. Is there a way to create a side menu in Eclipse. I need to create a fixed side menu not the menu bar. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to make a fixed side panel for a web application using Google Web Toolkit, you can use their [`DockLayoutPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html) class.  To make a 200px sidebar on the left side of the screen, you would declare your *.ui.xml file as follows:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
    <g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX">
        <g:west size="200">
            <g:Label>This is the side panel!</g:Label>
        </g:west>
        <g:center>
            <g:Label>This is the main panel.</g:Label>
        </g:center>
    </g:DockLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: Can you tell me in which folder to declare the *.ui.xml file and how should it be named(best naming practice) and how does this file associate with the DockLayoutPanel

Comment: The file can be in any folder you want, but should have the same name as the Java class.  If you have the Google Plugin for Eclipse, it will do all of that for you.  I'm not sure what you mean by asking how it "associates with the DockLayoutPanel".

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Checked out a few tutorials: http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2302. But I am having another problem now; I have created a structure as you have shown above but I cannot see the content of the horizontal panel which I created inside the <g:center></g:center>. The content is a static html table.